# Comparing strings on Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, compare

I'm new to programming in Ruby and I decided to learn to build a hangman game, but I have a problem when comparing two strings, one that comes from a gets (If I do it for me code works normal) and one that is defined.

this is my codes:

this is my 'main':

```
require_relative("Ahorcado")
juego = Ahorcado.new()
juego.decirPalabra

while juego.hayVidas?
  juego.imprimir 
  lectura = gets
  lectura = lectura.to_s;
  juego.preguntar lectura
end
puts juego.resultado
```

And the Ahorcado.rb

```
class Ahorcado
  def loadVariables
    @palabras = ["java","ruby","python","go"]
    @adivinados = []
    @gano = false
    @vidas = 7
  end

  def initialize
    loadVariables();
    @palabra = @palabras[rand(@palabras.length)].split("")
    puts "Se ha iniciado un juego"
    @tamano = @palabra.length
    puts "Existen #{@tamano} letras"
    iniciar
  end

  def decirPalabra
    puts @palabra
  end

  def preguntar letra
    @vidas -= 1
    letra = letra.to_s
    temp = @palabra.join
    puts temp.eql?(letra) # -> Allways false
    if letra == @palabra.join then
      @gano = true
      puts "gano"
    else
      for i in 0...@tamano
        if letra.eql?(@palabra[i]) then #Allways false
          @adivinados[i] = true
          @vidas += 1
        else
          puts "Incorrecto intente otra vez"
        end
      end
    end

  end

  def comparar letra
    @temp = letra;
    puts @temp == @palabra[0]
  end

  def iniciar
    for i in (0...@tamano)
      @adivinados[i] = false;
    end
  end

  def hayVidas?
    return @vidas > 0
  end

  def resultado
    @gano;
  end

  def imprimir
    for i in (0...@tamano)
      if @adivinados[i] then
        print @palabra[i]+" "
      else
        print "_ "
      end
    end
    puts
  end
end
```

Thanks for yours answers, and sorry if i wrote bad some sentences, i don't speak english

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: If I enter `lectura = gets` and then enter the name of my dog, `gets` returns `"Diva\n"`.  Firstly, I see you convert `lectura` to a string: `lectura.to_s`.  That's not necessary, because `gets` will always return a string. (Even if I enter "123", it will return "123\n").  Secondly, you will normally want to use `"Diva"`, rather than `"Diva\n"`, so you might want to [String#chomp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) off the newline character: `lectura = gets.chomp #=> "Diva"` (or as @Uri suggests, use `strip!` or `strip`). Could that be part of your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply i can fix the issue and now i can continue learning...

I use chomp and strip and both works

Answer (score 1):

When you do a "gets", lectura contains newline character in the end. Trying doing a "chomp" on lectura :-
    lectura = lectura.chomp
and try again. So that all the newline characters are removed.  You can also use "bytes" to see the exact characters in your string for debugging purposes.
    puts lectura.bytes

Refer:- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp